Customs for a ceremony for changing back the Torah covers
We would like to make a special ceremony for changing back our Torah covers (me'ilim) after the High Holidays. Are there any special readings and/or prayers said when changing the Torah covers from white to their regular covers after the High Holidays? Are there any known related established customs?

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Sorry to disappoint you, but the answer is no. In general making new ceremonies is not a good idea.

Welcome to MiYodeya Bill and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

We normally do this morning after Simchat Torah, before/after first minyan, takes 5 minutes and off we go to the new year ! Never saw a "ceremony" and wonder what you would be "celebrating"

@mbloch Some do it after Shabbat Bereishit, some do it on Simchat Torah itself (as gelila), some do it on hoshana rabba (when kabalistically the yamim noraim theme ends), and some do it after yom kippur (when originally the yamim noraim theme ends)

Did you have a ceremony when you put them on? (Or when you changed the covers for other events, like pesach or tisha bav?)
